# I want to write a procedure with input parameter as single or multiple values and return a ref cursor as per the input

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to implement as below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INPUT_XML (v_sne_id varchar2(10) -- input can be single or multiple values, 
                              v_card_name varchar2(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
                              v_port_no varchar2(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
                              v_refcur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

AS

BEGIN
IF (card_name is null and port_no is null )
then
open v_refcur for
select * from table where sne_id in (all the input sneId(s) );
end if;
END INPUT_XML:
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: I am not able to take input for multiple v_sne_id as a collection or as a array

Answer (score 3):

You may create and use a User-defined collection `TYPE` with `TABLE` function.

Type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE sne_id_type IS TABLE OF varchar2(10);
```

Procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE input_xml (
     v_sne_id    sne_id_type,  --use the parameter of the collection type
     v_card_name VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     v_port_no   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
     v_refcur    OUT      SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN
     IF ( v_card_name IS NULL AND v_port_no IS NULL ) THEN
          OPEN v_refcur FOR SELECT *
                            FROM tablename
                            WHERE sne_id IN ( SELECT column_value
                                              FROM TABLE ( v_sne_id )
                                            );

     END IF;
END input_xml;
/
```

To pass multiple values while executing, you may do

```
BEGIN
  INPUT_XML(sne_id_type('ID1','ID2','ID3'), 'CARD', null,null);
END;
/
```